# Dynamic add comment on table or view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to add comment on table or view with procedure using dynamic SQL.

I have tried this but unsuccessfully:

```
create or replace procedure add_comment(
  p_table   in varchar2,
  p_comment in varchar2
)
as

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'comment on table "' || p_table || '" is 

    ' || p_comment || '  end;'

      ;  
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL should be edited to avoid the `end` and handle the quotes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comment(p_table IN VARCHAR2, p_comment IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'comment on table "' || p_table || '" is     
    ''' || p_comment || '''';
END;
```